# Overloading a class with an object getting error?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

I'm simply trying to send an instance of `GameClass` into a `constructor` for a `form` in c#, getting

> Inconsistent accessibility: parameter type 'GameClass' is less
>   accessible than method 'frmGame.frmGame(GameClass)'

Here's the relevant code:

`Constructor` for `frmGame`:

```
private GameClass game;

public frmGame(GameClass game)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.game = game;
}
```

`OnClick` `event` for the previous `form`:

```
    private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GameClass game = new GameClass();
        Player[] players = new Player[pNum];

        players[0] = new Player(txbPlayer1.Text);

        if (!txbPlayer2.Visible)
        {
            players[1] = new Player(txbPlayer2.Text);
        }

        frmGame gameFrm = new frmGame(game);
        gameFrm.ShowDialog();
    }
```

EDIT:***Fixed it, had my GameClass as `class GameClass` instead of `public class GameClass`***

Comment: I read that but I don't quite understand

Comment: You have a public constructor. I assume that `GameClass` is *not* a public class. Either make your constructor `internal`, or make `GameClass` public. (There are lots of other questions on the same topic.)

Comment: Why are you sending `game` to `frmGame`, if it's just an empty new instance? The form can create it itself instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The message pretty much says what the issue is, right? You must have declared class `GameClass` as `private` or `internal`, which means it is only known by its containing class or assembly. Therefore, how can `frmGame` be called from *outside* if it must receive a `GameClass` as a parameter?

A method cannot have a parameter which is less accessible than the method itself. It wouldn't make sense otherwise.

Either `GameClass` should be `public`, or `frmGame` should have the same (or less) accessibility level than `GameClass`.

Update based on your edit: if you don't specify an accessibility level, by default it will be the lowest possible one. In this case, it was probably `internal`, unless it was inside another class.

Comment: That makes sense, but how would I transfer this object from my previous form to the next one, would I just make GameClass public then?

Comment: One thing is the accessibility level of a class, and another thing is the accessibility level of a specific instance of that class. `String` is a `public` class, but you can have a `private string`. Anyone else can create a string, but only your class can access that particular string. You must have this in mind when designing your application. My guess is that `GameClass` should be `public` (or `internal` if it will only be accessed from the same project) and your `GameClass game` object can remain `private`.

Comment: Thank you for explaining it to me, I understand now :)

Comment: I'm glad I was of help. If you feel my answer solved your problem, please mark it as accepted so your question doesn't remain unsolved. Thanks.